# javascript event handling

Tags: javascript, html, css

want to create a password field where I want to check for capsLock on/off on keystroke. Once a user enters a value in smallcase and try to another field want to validate the password value. Thus want to use onkeypress for every key pressed and then onblur at the end.

But the problem I am facing is every time onkeypress is checked onblur is also executed.

```
<input type="password" size=50  id='r5PswFld' name="name" value="" onkeypress="checkCapsLock(event)" onblur=chkPsw(this.id) >
```

can anyone help me how to attain this.

thanks in advance...

better if I am able to do this using only javascript/html/css I me no other technologies like jquery...

Comment: I hope this isn't your only validation checkpoint... validating only with Client-Side code is a recipe of disaster.

Comment: Good point.  You're just asking for trouble if you don't perform server-side validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This event is getting fired because you in checking the other checkbox input, you are blurring focus away from the current control.

Attach the onblur at the start your `checkCapsLock(event)` :

```
document.getElementById("r5PswFld").onblur = function(chkPsw(this.id)'){};
```

If you find yourself having to perform an action that will focus away, detach it:

```
document.getElementById("r5PswFld").onblur = function(){};
```

Next time you fire `checkCapsLock` it will reacttach if you need to. You could then also remove the `onblue` attribute completely from your code.

That said, be careful of any `onblur` validation. If is obtrusive (like an `alert`) then it could quickly get very frustrating for the user.

**EDIT**

In repose to the comment below, I thought I'd correct for the problem of other blur bindings. I'll use jQuery for preference.

The correct solution would look something like:

```
function MyBlurFunc(){
    chkPsw(this.id);
}
```

To bind:

```
$("#r5PswFld").blur(MyBlurFunc);
```

To unbind

```
$("#r5PswFld").unbind('blur', MyBlurFunc);
```

Comment: I won't vote it down because in 99% of the cases it'd work, but consider the 1% in which some javascript library overrides your blur method and then calls it.  You're undermining all methods using blur event, not just yours.

Comment: @Neil: Very generous of you, neil. You are, of course correct. I'll edit my answer to correct for this.

Comment: @Neil: There you go. Hope this meets your approval ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, onblur will get called whenever focus is left from the field, meaning if you open some sort of message box informing the user of having capslock on, you're removing focus and thus trigger the onblur event.

An alternative might be to activate a flag which you assign to be true prior to opening a message box so that in the case in which you enter chkPsw, you can ignore it.

In other words:

```
var flgEventsOff = false;
function checkCapsLock(event) {
    if (fieldValueIsUpper) {
        flgEventsOff = true;
        alert('Please turn off capslock!');
        flgEventsOff = false;
    }
}

function chkPsw(id) {
    if(!flgEventsOff) {
        // Validate password
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the blur event won't be executed the same time a keyPress event is fired. I assume you have an `alert()` statement within your `checkCapsLock()` event handler, which causes the loss of focus.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you not just change it to lowecase on the onblur event before it validates?

Comment: Do you have an answer or just a question?